# What is the htaccess syntax for preventing multiple urls from being created ?start=

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following redirect results in having "?start=12" appended:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/10-blood?start=12$ http://www.example.com/blood/blood-product
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Short answer : use mod_rewrite

Answer (score 5):

Add a `?` to the end of the target so that it's

```
http://www.example.com/blood/blood-product?
```

This will, however, make it so there's a stray `?` at the end of the URL in the browser's location bar. The only other way around this is to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=12$
RewriteRule ^products/10-blood$ http://www.example.com/blood/blood-product? [L,R=301]
```

With mod_rewrite, the `?` won't appear at the end but it will make it so any existing query string won't get appended.

Comment: so how come some of the urls are redirecting to http://www.example.com/blood/blood-product/index.php and the others are not appending index.php ?